# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u263a' in position 124: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, encoding

I understand the error is something related to charector encoding, but not sure how to fix it.

Error details:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u263a' in position 124: character maps to <undefined>
```

here is the error happening:

```
csv_writer.writerow(data_tmp_dict)
```

Comment: you are trying to write some character here, that is not representable by your default-encoding

Comment: what could be the fix here? how do I know my default encoding and what to change to? thoughts?

Comment: sys.getdefaultencoding()
Out[12]: 'utf-8'

Comment: share you code in detail ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to decode it to `UTF-8`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
data_tmp_dict = {'key': 'value'.encode("utf-8")}
# or
data_tmp_dict = {'key': 'value'.encode("ascii")}
```

Comment: my current encoding says utf-8. sys.getdefaultencoding() 'utf-8'

Comment: try `ascii` in place of `utf-8`

Comment: data_temp_dict is a dictionary, AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'